# How to delete a shipment from Magento that was created accidentally?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

How can I remove a shipment that was created accidentally?  I know there is no way to do it through the admin, but I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to revert an order back to a status of "Processing" along with all the old shipment information so it can be shipped at a later time.  I'm hoping this can be done programmatically via PHP or even just directly in MySQL.

FYI, I'm using Magento version 1.1.8.

Comment: how is this related to programming?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically using PHP or directly through MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up purchasing the extension below which did the trick beautifully.  Even though it doesn't say it supports versions prior to 1.3, it worked flawlessly on my setup of v1.1.8.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-shipment-6498.html

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
require_once  'app/Mage.php';

Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);


//Update Order id
$orderId = xyz;


$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

// check if has shipments
if(!$order->hasShipments()){
    die('No Shipments');
}

//delete shipment
$shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
foreach ($shipments as $shipment){
    $shipment->delete();
}

// Reset item shipment qty
// see Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getSimpleQtyToShip()
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $i){
   $i->setQtyShipped(0);
   $i->save();
}

//Reset order state
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Undo Shipment');
$order->save();

echo 'Done';
```

Comment: Great help. Just one change. In my case shipment was created but invoice was not done so i changed
 Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING  to Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW

Comment: This uses the orderId. It may be useful to use the order increment ID (which is what you see in the frontend and admin) in which case 
 use:loadByIncrementId($orderId) instead of the load($orderId);

Answer (score 0):

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shippingOrderId);
$shipment->delete();
```

I assume this works. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Unfortunately a few more things needed to happen otherwise the order wouldn't be able to be shipped again, the items were still marked as shipped and the order was still marked as complete. However, I found an extension that worked great.  I'll post it as an answer.  Thanks, though!

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.'

Comment: @Theodores - Add `Mage::app('admin');` above the code to resolve that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Say you shipped an order in its entirety and didn't mean to. Just delete the INVOICE. It will remove the invoice and any of the shipments...SHIPMENTS plural!

So you have to be careful, if you have other shipments you will need to recreate them. Then invoice it again. Then it will be just like you never shipped anything and you can then SHIP whatever quantity you originally required.

Comment: This answer needs clarification. By default, Magento's admin panel does not have any "Delete" option for invoices. Are you instructing the OP to programmatically delete the invoice?